# Why it shows me "This site can’t be reached"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I cannot get `projects` because it write me "This site can’t be reached". what I did wrong? I run on MacOS

[image]

Controller code

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/api/projects")]
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TasksDBContext _context;

        public ProjectsController(TasksDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
 
        
        //[HttpGet("/api/projects")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> Get()
        {
            return await _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Tasks).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your application running and listening on port 5001?

Comment: Yes, my app running and it is listening on port 5001

Comment: You have a constructor that takes a `TasksDBContext`. How are you passing the context to the controller? In my tests, the constructor is the problem. Removing the constructor makes it work. I would put a breakpoint on the constructor and in the `Get` method and see if you're even getting there.

Comment: @ShawnOrr: I believe that would be using plain constructor injection, hence that should not be the issue in this case. BR

Comment: Does any endpoint in your app respond on https://localhost:5001, or is the error limited to this specific URL? Are you sure you are using https (we can't see that in your question). I failed to reproduce the error using your code. BR

Answer (score -1):

You try to access other correct routes to see if this happens again.

If the "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error persists, try the following methods:

1.Verify it by restarting your Internet Router.

2.Verify your internet connection is working without any interruption by visiting other websites.

3.Verify whether your ISP has blocked the website, which throws this error, simply by accessing it through another device.

4.If you’ve VPN installed and it’s active, try disconnecting it.

5.For a temporary basis, try accessing the website after disabling Firewall application.

6.Remove Cache Files

7.Delete & Reinstalling Google Chrome

Comment: what is the ISP for localhost?